# Not able to access internet in Firefox

Tags: firefox

I'm able to access the internet in other browsers except Firefox... After updating the browser I'm facing the issue. I tried by reinstalling the browser, still same issue I'm facing. Please, suggest me a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm using windows 7 - 64 bit OS

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I faced the same issue. I did all the things that they have listed in the mozilla forum for the same question and still it did not help.

It turns out, if your organisation is using a proxy, you might have to contact your admin. The standard answer in the mozilla forum is that you have to set the proxy setting to "none". But if your organisation is using a proxy then by default IE will have set the settings to desiganted proxy, but apparently mozilla has its own proxy settings.

So go to proxy settings in mozilla and make sure the settings there is similar to the one in IE. I set the proxy to detect automatically and it worked.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Did you have any anti-virus software installed? If so, please take a look at the following article from mozilla:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/fix-problems-connecting-websites-after-updating

Comment: Hi Faulancer, Thanks for the response.. :)
I have uninstalled my antivirus, still I'm facing the issue :(